# How can I force the app to use a specific locale when I change the device locale?

Tags: android, localization

I have an app that has strings in french and german. I have placed these strings in `values-fr` and `values-de` respectively.

**Current state:**
Device Locale: en-US

When I launch the app, I want the app to show English (en-US). I only want the app to use french or german depending on a flag that I receive over an API. To do this, in the `Application.onCreate()`, I force the locale to English using this piece of code - `locale` is en-US in this case.

```
public void updateLocale(@NonNull Locale locale) {
  checkNotNull(locale);

  if (!getCurrentLocale().equals(locale)) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
      configuration.setLocale(locale);
    } else {
      configuration.locale = locale;
    }
    setCurrentLocale(locale);
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
  }
}
```

The current locale is written to and read from SharedPreferences through  `setCurrentLocale(Locale)` and `getCurrentLocale()` respectively.

When I change the device locale to fr-FR and come back to the app, the locale changes to french, but I **don't** want this to happen (because I have not made the API call to get the flag yet). I want to force English in the `onConfigurationChanged` method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  Locale newLocale;
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    newLocale = newConfig.getLocales().get(0);
  } else {
    newLocale = newConfig.locale;
  }

  if (!localeManager.isFlagTurnedOn()) {
    localeManager.updateLocale(LOCALE_ENGLISH);
  }
}
```

This does not work! The locale changes to french (if I change device locale to fr-FR) when I come back to the app. How can I prevent this from happening? Also, how do I ensure that the app does not default to system locale on changing to landscape?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!